# Simple browserify test only runs when built with --debug

Tags: browserify

I have a simple hello world script main.js:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = "Hello, browser.";
});
```

If I build bundle.js with:

```
browserify -r ./main.js > bundle.js
```

It doesn't run in the browser. No errors, just doesn't execute. If I use:

```
browserify -r --debug ./main.js > bundle.js
```

It runs fine. Why doesn't the non-debug one run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-r` means require. -> `-r file.js` means, that you will put it into a seperate scope to require it in an other bundle, but it don't will execute.

Your "solution" `-r --debug` (or short `-r -d`) works, because the `require` attribute has no parameter/file, so it will be ignored by browserify.

> Just removing `-r --debug` should solve your problem.

This...

```
browserify -r --debug ./main.js -o ./bundle.js
```

...is the same as this:

```
browserify -d ./main.js -o ./bundle.js
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I figured that out... I originally added -r because I was having trouble with `require` being undefined. Not sure how that happened because now it works.